# bytearray(b"\xd0xPx\xf0") meaning

Tags: python, arrays, sprite, display

I'm looking through someone's code that makes simple sprite for a space invader game. They use the following bytearray:

`bytearray(b"\xd0xPx\xf0")`

What is the xPx? With it, you get something that looks like a small object or space invader and without it, its just two lines. I've been seraching around and can't figure out what it means.

Comment: It's just a byte array with 5 bytes in it. `xPx` are just 3 of the bytes, expressed as ascii.

Comment: :facepalm: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!